# Count Distinct?

Tags: sql

I have a table "Purchases":

```
CustomerId . PurchaseYear . PurchaseMonth
1234       . 2012         . 6 
1235       . 2012         . 7
1236       . 2013         . 4
1237       . 2015         . 6
1238       . 2015         . 6
```

And I'm trying to count the number of customers who made a purchase in each month and year. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to include months any years where _no_ purchase was made?

Comment: Google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you don't need to include months where *no* purchase was made:

```
SELECT PurchaseYear, PurchaseMonth, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId)
FROM {table}
GROUP BY PurchaseYear, PurchaseMonth
```

Note that `COUNT(DISTINCT xxx)` works with all of the major SQL Systems but is not supported on some (like MS Access).

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is standard ANSI SQL and works with all (real) databases.  The one exception I can easily think of is MS Access.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I knew it was fairly universal but I don't use many of the smaller systems.

Answer (score 0):

Customer Purchases by Year

```
Select PurchaseYear, Count(DISTINCT CustomerId) As CustomerPurchases
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY PurchaseYear
```

Customer Purchases by Month

```
Select PurchaseYear, PurchaseMonth, Count(DISTINCT CustomerId) As CustomerPurchases
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY PurchaseYear, PurchaseMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desire result can be achieve using common query of group by.

```
Select PurchaseYear , PurchaseMonth, Count(CustomerId) as TotalCustomer, 
From Purchase 
Group by PurchaseYear, PurchaseMonth
```